# Javascript set input value when user click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Im developing chrome extension. I want to change input value(username) to some text when user click button. But my solution not working. Need advise.
My code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=utf8>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=windows-1254>
<META http-equiv=content-type content=text/html;charset=x-mac-turkish>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<title></title>
<script>
    $('#target').submit(function() {
    alert('something');
    return false;
    $('#UserName').value('test');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="target">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>UserName:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="UserName" size="20" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="password" id="Password" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Login" id="Login" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine

```
$('input#Login').click(function() {        
    $('#UserName').val('test');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your submit button needs to be of type **'submit'**.

So this:

```
<input type="button" value="Login" id="Login" />
```

should be:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" id="Login" />
```

Also, the appropriate jQuery function for getting/setting input values is **.val()**.

Lastly, you don't want to **return false** until the end of the function.

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
    alert('something');      
    $('#UserName').val('test');
    return false;
});
```

See this **working** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kx4EF/).

Comment: I looked in fidlle. Yes it works. But In my extension it doesnt work.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in your console? The above could is the correct way to complete the tasks you specified using jQuery.

Comment: I am developing chrome extension. When i open my html in browser all is fine and works. But when i install my extension into chrome nothing works. I clicked button to many times but it is refreshing page only there is no alert no error.

Answer (score 2):

Change your submit button from type button to submit from:

```
 <input type="button" value="Giriş" id="Login" />
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Giriş" id="Login" />
```

Also change your JS code from:

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
alert('uyarı');
return false;
$('#UserName').value('deneme');
```

to:

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
 alert('uyarı');    
 $('#UserName').val('deneme');
 return false;
```

Comment: Tried but nothing changed except form refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses the VAL rather than VALUE

in other words

```
<script>
    $('#target').submit(function() {
    alert('something');
    return false;
    $('#UserName').val('test');
});
</script>
```

and also the FORM is not submitado change the type of input and submit to the adciona FORM `METHOD = "POST"`

Comment: Thanks for answer but still nothing changed

Comment: @pale changed the response of a look

Comment: I am developing chrome extension. When i open my html in browser all is fine and works. But when i install my extension into chrome nothing works. I clicked button to many times but it is refreshing page only there is no alert no error. But when open in browser everythings works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you very much. I found. The problem is  when you are developing google chrome application you must seperate javascript code from html. Otherwise javascript not work.